# Syntax error on running a batch file to replace files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file intended to replace all instances of tracking.js within a folder/sub folders.

FOR /R "D:\Virtual Servers (Testing)\CourseWare Master\Shared\Jenison\Version1.2\" %%I IN (tracking.js*) DO COPY /Y "D:\Virtual Servers (Testing)\CourseWare Master\Shared\Jenison\tracking.js" %%~fI

When this is run I get the following syntax error

C:>COPY /Y "D:\Virtual Servers (Testing)\CourseWare Master\Shared\Jenison\track
ing.js" D:\Virtual Servers (Testing)\CourseWare Master\Shared\Jenison\Version1.2
\SHAPERS_COMBINED\Smarter Communications\WhatisInfluencing\script\Tracking.js
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Ideas please?

Comment: You have a space in the target path too - I think this should also be encapsulated with "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to quote `%%~fI` as it expands to a path with spaces.

```
FOR /R "D:\Virtual Servers (Testing)\CourseWare Master\Shared\Jenison\Version1.2\" %%I IN (tracking.js*) DO COPY /Y "D:\Virtual Servers (Testing)\CourseWare Master\Shared\Jenison\tracking.js" "%%~fI"
```